# "Could not authenticate you." -error when using Twitter OAuth

Tags: oauth, twitter

I'm building my first system using Twitters OAuth and have some issues.

First, I'm using Abraham's Twitter-class for this and I have followed [this](http://www.snipe.net/2009/07/writing-your-first-twitter-application-with-oauth/) tutorial. However, I get these lines on my callback.php:

```
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\twitterOAuth\OAuth.php on line 301

Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\twitterOAuth\OAuth.php on line 373
Oops - an error has occurred.
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [request] => /account/verify_credentials.xml
    [error] => Could not authenticate you.
)
```

Is this problem by Twitter-class, or am I doing something wrong? I have my Consumer Key and Consumer Secret in config.php as tutorial says, but should I store something else?

Martti Laine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Snipe.net tutorial is for an older version of TwitterOAuth. Make sure you read the new documentation

http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION

In general updating to the new version is changing:

`$content = $to->OAuthRequest('https://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml', array(), 'GET');`

to:

`$content = $to->get('account/verify_credentials');`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error, caused by a simple mistake:

Doesn’t work:
`$this->twitteroauth->post('statuses/update’, $message);`

Works: `$this->twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array("status" => $message));`