# Using Twitter API (Abraham lirbary)

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

So Im using Abrahams Twitter library like this:

Connect.php

```
/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
    case 200:
        /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
        $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
        header('Location: ' . $url); 
        break;
    default:
        /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
        echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

and index.php:

```
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
        $userInfo = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

But I keep getting the error:

"Could not authenticate you"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Could not authenticate you." -error when using Twitter OAuth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657452/could-not-authenticate-you-error-when-using-twitter-oauth)

Comment: ITs not duplicated. I already apply the solution thats written in that thread :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently after authentification, I have to replace the temporary authentification token, for a permanent one. Here it is:

Callback.php

```
/* Create TwitteroAuth object with app key/secret and token key/secret from default phase */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

/* Request access tokens from twitter */
$access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

/* Save the access tokens. Normally these would be saved in a database for future use. */
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

/* Remove no longer needed request tokens */
unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

/* If HTTP response is 200 continue otherwise send to connect page to retry */
if (200 == $connection->http_code) {
    /* The user has been verified and the access tokens can be saved for future use */
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'verified';
    header('Location: ./index.php');
} else {
    die("There was a problem!");
}
```